# Docker-compose and Docker-swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm using docker-compose and docker swarm. I have created a docker-mgt server from which I did a docker-machine to setup a swarm cluster consisting of a swarm master and two swarm-agents.

I have created an Express app that gets started in a container and it seems the swarm master decided to have it on agent1. Then I have also a Wordpress site (example from the docker compose site) that I'm running with docker-compose on Docker Swarm.

```
cloud-user@docker-mgt:~/wordpress$ docker-compose up
wordpress_db_1 is up-to-date
Creating wordpress_web_1
ERROR: Error: image library/wordpress_web:latest not found
```

The following images are available:

```
cloud-user@docker-mgt:~/wordpress$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
orchardup/php5      latest              c385b8a81cee        18 months ago       330.1 MB
swarm               latest              a9975e2cc0a3        19 hours ago        17.15 MB
orchardup/mysql     latest              5a45a5a953bb        16 months ago       292.4 MB
wordpress_web       latest              e484f88dc8c8        11 minutes ago      350.9 MB
node-ip             latest              d177af00338b        39 minutes ago      549.5 MB
centos              centos6             1a895dd3954a        8 weeks ago         190.6 MB
```

So it does have the wordpress_web:latest available and still it complains.

When running this wordpress app on a seperate docker host (not part of the swarm cluster) it runs just fine. To exclude a mistake on the wordpress app, I also tried another complete different app consisting of two containers (with docker-compose) and it is exactly the same issue.

I'm beginning to think that docker compose and swarm can not work together smoothly but that's hard to believe of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that swarm needs some way to retrieve the image to run the container. If the image doesn't exist in a registry (or the docker hub) then it doesn't (currently) have any way to get that image , and you end up with this error.

One option is to tag the images with a full name and push them to the hub. Then swarm will be able to pull the images on all the nodes.

Another options is to propagate the image using `docker save` and `docker load`, which will send the image to all nodes.

Another option is to add an [image affinity](http://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/filter/#image-affinity) to force the container to run on the node that has the image.

In the future, swarm should gain the ability to propagate images between nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I used docker hub and this seems to work indeed. However, I was surprised to see that docker-compose up results in launching both containers on the swarm-master, instead of one of both agents? Any idea why this is?

Comment: swarm has different scheduling strategies (https://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/strategy/). The default should be spread, so I would expect it to use a different host, but maybe if a container was recreated it got placed together. You can use an affinity or constraint to place it on a different node: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/filter/

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try out Rancher, it uses compose and makes it simple to deploy applications across broad types of infrastructure, while keeping native docker syntax and using compose.  [GitHub](http://github.com/rancher/rancher)  [Website](http://www.rancher.com)

Comment: Indeed, still on my to do list. Trying to get my head around docker and the many tools surrounding it. Also, CoreOS is on my todo-list.

Comment: Rancher uses compose-like format, but it is not actually compose, and you should expect some things to behave differently.